# pjproject => aconfigure: error: unable to use SRTP

Tags: webrtc, configure, rtp, pjsip

Hello I'm currently trying to build WebRTC on Asterisk, so far i've been following this site (http://www.nethram.com/webrtc-with-asterisk-12/) and get "aconfigure: error: unable to use SRTP" after running ./configure pjproject.
It gives me this notification about SRTP (since I configure it with "--with-external-srtp")

the error message (the others are working fine)==>
checking if external SRTP devkit is installed... aconfigure: error: Unable to use SRTP. If SRTP development files are not available in the default locations, use CFLAGS and LDFLAGS env var to set the include/lib paths

Can anybody help? Thank you very much

Comment: Try installing libsrtp0 and libsrtp0-dev using apt-get install libsrtp0 libsrtp0-dev

Comment: This fix appears to work for me, I  get the asterix ascii logo.

Comment: @SachinMuraliG Hi, any macos solution?

Answer (score 0):

Let's use v1.5.0 instead of current (v2.x)
git clone https://github.com/cisco/libsrtp/
cd libsrtp
git fetch
git tag -l
git checkout v1.5.0
..